# State element does not appear on react simple map with react-tooltip

Tags: json, reactjs, state

The code is working with the property 'name', names appear correctly on the map.

I wanted to enrich the json file with datas coming from my mysql database (like, add the name of countries in french or spanish for example).

I added a state 'countries' which will be initialized with json file converted in object. I fetch data from my sql database and then I set the state 'countries' with data I wanted to add.

Here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import {
  ComposableMap,
  ZoomableGroup,
  Geographies,
  Geography,
} from "react-simple-maps"
import ReactTooltip from "react-tooltip"
import jsonWorldMap from "./maps/world-50m.json"

const wrapperStyles = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  backgroundColor: "#0565A1"
}

class WorldMap extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()

    this.state = {
      zoom: 1,
      color: "#39464E",
      countries: jsonWorldMap
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    //get all countries in db
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/countries')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(body => 
        body.data.forEach(function(elementSql){
          jsonWorldMap.objects.units.geometries.forEach(function(elementJson){
            if(elementSql.alpha3 == elementJson.id)
            {
              elementJson.properties.nameFr = elementSql.name_fr;
            }
          })
        })
      )
      this.setState({ countries: jsonWorldMap }, () => console.log(this.state.countries))
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div style={wrapperStyles}>
        <ComposableMap>         
          <ZoomableGroup center={[0,20]}>
            <Geographies geography={this.state.countries}>
              {(geographies, projection) => geographies.map((geography, i) => geography.id !== "ATA" && (
                <Geography
                  className="Geography"
                  key={i}
                  data-tip={geography.properties.nameFr}
                  geography={geography}
                  projection={projection}
                />
              ))}
            </Geographies>
          </ZoomableGroup>
        </ComposableMap>
        <ReactTooltip />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default WorldMap
```

So you can see that I added a component to have a console.log at the end of the component. See what console.log gives :

[image]

So you can see that the property 'nameFr' is present in the state object 'countries'. But, If I try to display it as tooltip, it doesn't work. And it works perfectly with property 'name' (in data-tip)

Comment: Can you confirm that you are getting an updated state value for countries after the componentDidMount. You can check by doing this.setState({ countries: jsonWorldMap }, () => console.log(this.state.countries))

Comment: I confirm. I wrote exactly what you wrote at the end of componentDidMount() method. I have the nameFr property in properties.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the `return false` in your ConsoleLog function?

Comment: Edited. The component ConsoleLog is not here anymore. Same problem.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect your component using react devtools in chrome?

Comment: If I load the page for the first time, names are in english. If I do something like a click on the page, the name becomes in french and the map is so loaded correctly. I don't understand really.

Comment: @Kuartz check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  `data-tip={geography.properties.name}` works fine but `data-tip={geography.properties.nameFr}` does not, then it seems that the problem is with state.

See your componentDidMount method. You are updating state with jsonWorldMap at the end of this method.

But as fetch is async , at that moment jsonWorldMap may not be updated yet. So I think you should move that line inside fetch. please see below:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const _this = this; // hold this inside _this
    //get all countries in db
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/countries')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(body => {
        body.data.forEach(function(elementSql){
          jsonWorldMap.objects.units.geometries.forEach(function(elementJson){
            if(elementSql.alpha3 == elementJson.id)
            {
              elementJson.properties.nameFr = elementSql.name_fr;
            }
          })
        });
        _this.setState({ countries: jsonWorldMap }, () => console.log(this.state.countries)); //making sure setting updated jsonWorldMap to state
      }
      )     
  }
```

hope it helps.

thanks

Comment: It helps a lot. And you just solved my problem ! Thanks ! (I put the setState into 'then' in order to add this in promise. Then the data are avaible when the state is updated). I also found that if nameFr property is not present in json, even if it's empty, nothing appears on the map. But I tried on some countries to add this property empty in json, the good data is displayed. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Geography with an element that uses `data-tip` as a `props`.

```js
<div data-tip={geography.properties.nameFr}>
  <Geography ... />
</div>
```

In order to `<Geography data-tip={props.nameFr}/>` work, `Geography` component need to use the `data-tip` property internaly, something like:

```
function Geography(props) {
  return <h1 data-tip={props['data-tip']}>I'm a map</h1>;
}
```

To solve your problem you need to attach `data-tip` property to `Geography` wrapper, for example:

```js
function Geography(props) {
  return <h1>I'm a map</h1>;
}

function ComponentWithTooltip({ props }) {
  return (
    <div data-tip="nameFr">
      <Geography />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Geography data-tip="hello-world" />    // Your way, won't work

      <ComponentWithTooltip />                // Work

      <div data-tip="nameFr2">                // Work
        <Geography />
      </div>

      // Works with div wrapper, without won't work.
      {geographies.map((geofraphy, i) => (
        <div key={i} data-tip={geofraphy.properties.nameFr}>
          <Geography />
        </div>
      ))}

      <ReactTooltip />
    </>
  );
}
```

Check out the demo with all use cases:

[image: Edit cocky-dust-wsvtu]

Comment: So to solve the problem, what exactly would you write in my code?

Comment: Just wrap it with `div` when you mapping, `<div data-tip={geography.properties.nameFr}>
  <Geography ... />
</div>`

Comment: Map does not appear anymore. I did a repo on Github : https://github.com/Ku4rtz/travel_memories